# refresh select after Ajax load option called on click of select

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, select, dynamic

not had much luck researching this atm. a lot on mobile jquery but not standard.

basically i have a standard select list with a few php loaded options. what im doing is when the user clicks on the select it call an ajax request that loads extra options into the select menu based on other variables. simple enough, BUT the select menu does not reload the list until the menu is refocused (clicked off and on again).

i have tried the `.selectmenu('refresh', true);` and `.trigger('refresh');` but i do not think  this is what these functions are meant for, and as you can guess do not work.

Any ideas or anyone solved this problem? im sure i've seen this done on other websites with a load symbol, but atm im guessing this probably was not a select but some kind of customised UL.

i cant have my users clicking a menu just to click it off and click again, and do not want to have to ajax load on click of seperate button as this is supposed to be a quick function.

also i cannot have it loaded when the variable is set.

Comment: Menu refresh work maybe your ajax is the problem. Post all code.

See here: [http://jsfiddle.net/HVahC/](http://jsfiddle.net/HVahC/)

Comment: nope cant be ajax as i have tested only the update using dummy data and a jquery append `$('#selectbox').click(function() {
                 $this = $(this); 
     setTimeout(function(){$this.append('<option>Test Success</option>').trigger('refresh');},4000);
            });
`  if I click the select and wait the drop down menu does not get populated with test data until i click off and then click back on it, as per stated in my question. please read properly, im not that much of a noob.

Comment: EDIT- although i have forgotten to check Xbrowser, this does work in FF but i am using webkit based browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this way, return false on the click event of #id_select-button , jquery mobile add the '-button' and open the options manually.

```
$('#select-choice-1-button').click(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#select-choice-1').append('<option value="gg">TEST SUCCESS</option>');
        $('#select-choice-1').selectmenu('refresh');
        $('#select-choice-1').selectmenu('open');
    }, 2000);

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HVahC/1/

Comment: aha yes, do it the other way round, this sounds like the closest i am going to get to my goal. was hoping to show a loading symbol within the list but with your code i could absolute a load on top of the select before opening. Thanks muchly dude.